# Why time.Time not equal after bson.Marshal and bson.Unmarshal?

Tags: go

Why does it output `false`? I was expecting `true`...

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    )

type S struct {
    T time.Time
}
func main() {
    t := S{time.Now()}
    bytes, _ := bson.Marshal(t)
    var dt S
    bson.Unmarshal(bytes, &dt)
    fmt.Println(dt.T.Equal(t.T))
}
```

`go run` the above will output `false`, why `Marshal/Unmarshal` doesn't preserve the original value?

Comment: Please format your code with `go fmt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bson stores time with lower precision than a `time.Time`, the value returned from Bson may not equal the value you stored.
You need to use [`bson.Now()`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Now):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "time"
)

type S struct {
    T time.Time
}

func main() {
    t := S{bson.Now()}
    bytes, _ := bson.Marshal(t)
    var dt S
    bson.Unmarshal(bytes, &dt)
    fmt.Println(dt.T)
    fmt.Println(t.T)
    fmt.Println(dt.T.Equal(t.T))
}
```

Output:

```
$> go run main.go 
2018-09-08 10:48:42.45 +0300 MSK
2018-09-08 10:48:42.45 +0300 MSK
true
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the relevant BSON encoding code is here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/encode.go#L388 . It only encodes the time up to millisecond precision while `time.Time` stores the time to nanosecond precision. When encoding, information about the time higher than millisecond precision is lost.